# Fastest way to access sprite sheet for HTML5 game app

Tags: css, database, html, sprite

i am building a HTML5 app where about 1000+ images from a sprite sheet is accessed.

Currently i am accessing the images from a database, and it has a small time delay of about 200ms. I've checked and it's not the onlick or touch events thats causing the problem. is there a better alternative rather than accessing a database...say save the images in Java classes?

If I do it in XML and reference the images through DOM, it may be quite complicated to keep on looking up the entire page (or even by ID).

Constructive suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use CSS image sprites perhaps.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp